# Unity C# how to change bool in function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently writing an application in **C#** with **Unity**, and I've hit a small stumbling block. I'm trying to change the value of a bool in the `buyBusinessCourse()` method of a class, but the value is unaffected. The initial value of the **boolean** is set to `false`, then I want the update method to run an if statement if it returns true.

```
   public Text healthText;
    public Text hungerText;
    public Text moneyText;
    public Text ageText;
    public GameObject youDied;
    public GameObject notEnoughMoney;
    public GameObject mainScreenPanel;
    public GameObject healthPanel;
    public GameObject hungerPanel;
    public GameObject storePanel;
    public GameObject moneyPanel;
    public GameObject bicycleImage;
    public GameObject businessButton;
    public GameObject boughtBusiness;
    public int health;
    public int hunger;
    public int money;
    public int age;
    private  bool business;

public void buyBusinessCourse()
    {
        if (money >= 3000)
        {
            money -= 3000;
            moneyText.text = "Money: " + money;
            Debug.Log("1");
            businessButton.SetActive(false);
            boughtBusiness.SetActive(true);
            bool business = true;
            Debug.Log(business);
            return;
        }
        else
        {           
            StartCoroutine(notEnoughMoneyCaroutine());
            Debug.Log("2");
        }

    }
 private void Start()
    {
        bool business = false;
        Debug.Log(business);

    }

    //Update 
private void Update()
{
    if (health<0 | hunger<0 )
    {
        youDied.SetActive(true);
        mainScreenPanel.SetActive(false);
        healthPanel.SetActive(false);
        hungerPanel.SetActive(false);
        storePanel.SetActive(false);
        moneyPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    if (business == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("update"+business);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `bool business = true;` defines a variable local to the method it is declared in. This variale has no relation to the `bool business;` field in the class. To set the field `bussines`, just use `business = true;` (without the "bool" in front").

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to respecify the type, just do business = true. However you are creating a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

You've redefined business in if statement.

```
public void buyBusinessCourse()
    {
        if (money >= 3000)
        {
...
            bool business = true;
...
```

If you want to change the value of the `business` bool you need to write `this.business=true`  or `business=true`.

```
public void buyBusinessCourse()
    {
        if (money >= 3000)
        {
...
            this.business = true;
...
```

**Example**

```
class Rect {
  private int width;
  private int height;

  Rect(int width, int height) {
    this.width=width; //Change the value of 'width member of Rect class'
    this.height=height; //Change the value of height to given parameter.  
  }
  changeWidthToTen() {
    this.width=10;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually you don't need ```this.***``` since C# ?version released. You can call directly by writing name of the member for example: ```width=10```.